# Fast Numpy calculation of a slight variation of the repeat and choose functions

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, scientific-computing

I would like to use numpy to solve a problem that is very similar, but not quite identical, to the problem solved by the numpy.repeat function. I do not see how to solve this problem using any of the numpy functions I am familiar with, so I'm looking for help to see whether this can be done with numpy. My arrays are large (>1e6 elements), and high-performance is critical, so I cannot afford the performance hit of a python for loop.

### Minimal example

I have a length-num_pts sorted integer array `objID` that stores (possibly repeated) object identifiers.

```
objID = np.array([0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8])
```

I determine the unique entries of `objID`, and the indices of their appearance in `objID`, using numpy.unique.

```
unique_objIDs, idx_unique_objIDs = np.unique(objID, return_index=True)
num_unique_objIDs = len(unique_objIDs)
```

I also have a length-num_unique_objIDs array `occupations` that specifies how many times I want to select each entry of `unique_objIDs` from `objID`.

```
occupations = np.array([0, 2, 1, 2])
```

I want to determine the array of indices that I can use to retrieve elements of `objID` according to `occupations`. I give a specific example below.

```
desired_array_of_indices = np.array([2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```

The array `desired_array_of_indices` is what I want to use numpy to calculate. The entries of `desired_array_of_indices` are calculated as follows.

### Explicit explanation of `desired_array_of_indices`

Element-i of the `occupations` array specifies how many times `unique_objID[i]` will be selected. The `desired_array_of_indices` array stores the indices of `objID` of these selections. For values of `objID` that are selected more than once, *successive* indices of `objID` are chosen, so that no indices stored in `desired_array_of_indices` are repeated.

For concreteness, consider the first element of `occupations`. The value is zero, telling us that we do not want to select any indices of `objID` that store `unique_objIDs[0]=0`, so all such indices are left out of `desired_array_of_indices`.

The next element of `occupations` is 2, telling us that we want to select the indices of the first 2 appearances of `unique_objIDs[1]=5` in `objID`. This is why the first two entries of `desired_array_of_indices` are 2 and 3.

The next element of `occupations` is 1, telling us that we want to select the index of the first appearance of `unique_objIDs[2]=7` in `objID`. So the next entry of `desired_array_of_indices` is 5.

The last element of `occupations` is 2, telling us that we want to select the indices of the first 2 appearances of `unique_objIDs[3]=8` in `objID`. This is why the last two entries of `desired_array_of_indices` are 6 and 7.

### Difference from np.repeat

Note the subtle difference between this calculation and `numpy.repeat`. For `numpy.repeat`, the returned indices pertain to the array of unique entries, `unique_objIDs`. Here I need the indices of `objID`, and I also need to select successive indices for cases of repeated entries. Each entry of `occupations` can be assumed to be less than or equal to the total number of times the corresponding entry appears in `objID`, so there is no danger of an indexing error.

Does anyone see how to formulate this problem in terms of (possibly some collection of) available vectorized Numpy functions?

Comment: sounds like a job for cumsum and searchsorted; interesting problem but I cant work it out right now, got to run. if its still open, Ill try tomorrow morning.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn - I hadn't thought of np.cumsum but at least intuitively I see why you suggest it. Nice idea. I'll try that angle and see if I can make it fit. I'll post an answer if I figure it but I'll continue to leave it open if I don't. This is one of those problems that just feels like there *must* be a clever way to do it in pure numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way.

First, your example code:

```
In [102]: objID = np.array([0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8])

In [103]: unique_objIDs, idx_unique_objIDs = np.unique(objID, return_index=True)
```

*[[Note: `unique()` sorts its argument.  You know your input is already sorted, so a more efficient way to get `idx_unique_objIDs` is:*

```
idx_unique_objIDs = np.concatenate(([0], np.nonzero(np.diff(objID))[0] + 1))
```

*This operation is O(n) instead of the O(n*log(n)) required by `unique`.  Then you can use*

```
unique_objIDs = objID[idx_unique_objIDs]
```

*if you need the array of the unique object IDs.]]*

```
In [104]: occupations = np.array([0, 2, 1, 2])
```

Now find the desired indices. The result is in line `Out[107]`:

```
In [105]: csum = occupations.cumsum()

In [106]: n = csum[-1]

In [107]: np.arange(n) + np.repeat(idx_unique_objIDs - csum + occupations, occupations)
Out[107]: array([2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```

A closer look:

`csum` is the cumulative sum of `occupations`, and `n` is the total of `occupations`:

```
In [114]: csum
Out[114]: array([0, 2, 3, 5])

In [115]: n
Out[115]: 5
```

`csum` can be interpreted as the index of the *end* of the range of indices (pythonic "end", that is) associated with each occupation.  Then `csum - occupations` holds the indices of the beginnings of the ranges:

```
In [116]: csum - occupations
Out[116]: array([0, 0, 2, 3])
```

Repeat those starting indices according to the values in `occupations`:

```
In [117]: np.repeat(csum - occupations, occupations)
Out[117]: array([0, 0, 2, 3, 3])
```

If that is subtracted from `np.arange(n)`, we have, for each occupation `k`, a range from 0 to `occupation[k]-1` concatenated in an array:

```
In [118]: np.arange(n) - np.repeat(csum - occupations, occupations)
Out[118]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

That's not quite the desired result.  We have to add the (repeated) `idx_unique_objIDs` so that the values are indices into the array `objID`:

```
In [119]: np.arange(n) - np.repeat(csum - occupations, occupations) + np.repeat(idx_unique_objIDs, occupations)
Out[119]: array([2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```

Now combine those two `repeat()` calls to get the final expression:

```
In [120]: np.arange(n) + np.repeat(idx_unique_objIDs - csum + occupations, occupations)
Out[120]: array([2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```

Comment: Very clever @Warren Weckesser! This looks like *exactly* the clever application/variation of np.repeat that I was looking for. This looks correct and certainly returns the correct array for the minimal example I gave; just let me try out your solution within my test suite and then I'll mark it as accepted. Very nice work.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion, with `return_counts` instead of `return_index`:

```
unique_objIDs, objID_counts = np.unique(objID, return_counts=True)
num_unique_objIDs = len(unique_objIDs)

yesno = np.tile([True, False], num_unique_objIDs)
amounts = np.c_[occupations, objID_counts-occupations].ravel()
desired_array_of_indices = np.flatnonzero(np.repeat(yesno, amounts))
```

Comment: Interesting solution @morningsun, and also very fast for large arrays. I don't follow your usage of np.c_, I'm not familiar with this function. Can you explain a bit more about what's going on with this part and the remainder of the solution?